# Prepend to input using bootstrap BUT while using "form-group row" send to the next line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a form using bootstrap 4.
The labels and inputs are on the same line by using class='form-group row'.
I want to prepend the $ sign before an input.
When I try all examples that I can find online, it sends the input to the next line.

Here is the code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="msrp" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-right">MSRP</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
    </div>
    <input onBlur='this.value = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2)' type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" name="msrp" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what it looks like.... [Screenshot of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdIqz.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I spent a lot of time on google trying to find the answer myself.  Lots of examples found, but none where the label and input were on the same line, like how I want my form to be formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a div with the class of `input-group` before your `input-group-prepend` class, modify your code to look like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/) is a link to the appropriate section of Bootstrap's docs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks paul-schultz... after some tinkering this worked.  I posted the code so others would see exactly where it needs to be to get it to work... also a screenshot!  Thanks again!

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="msrp" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-right">MSRP</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class=input-group>
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
      </div>
      <input onBlur='this.value = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2)' type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" name="msrp" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Heres the result [RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Rul.png)